# gcloud auth does not work out with windows WSL

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-authentication

I tried to authenticate with gcp using my personal account, but I can able to make it work entirely.

so I tried doing it using
[image]

when I copy the same url and paste it into the browser, it is not working, see this
[image]

Not sure why this is now happening, as it is the WSL - ubuntu machine on windows does not have web browser attached to terminal, so I had to do it manually paste into web which is not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I missed, instead of `gcloud auth` I need to do this -

```
gcloud init --console-only
```

which works out the way I expected. (I copied the url from console paste it into console where verification code)

Answer (score 4):

```
gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser
```

ref: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing